# Registering different implementation of a service for auththenticated and non-authenticated users?

Tags: laravel, architecture, middleware

I would like to be able to register different implementation of a service based on wether user is authenticated or not.

But from what i have found so far the problem is that ServiceProviders get executed before the authentication middleware, hence the `auth()->check()` always return false.

So is there a way to achieve this?

or should I just create a factory class, which resolves the needed instance?

Any other ways to do it?

Comment: Opinion based? Can whoever voted this elaborate how this is opinion based?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Register Service Bindings:

Create Interfaces and Implementations:

```
// app/Services/AuthService.php
namespace App\Services;
interface AuthService {
   public function authenticate();
}

// app/Services/AuthenticatedAuthService.php
namespace App\Services;

class AuthenticatedAuthService implements AuthService {
public function authenticate() {
    // Implementation for authenticated users
}

// app/Services/NonAuthenticatedAuthService.php
namespace App\Services;
class NonAuthenticatedAuthService implements AuthService {
public function authenticate() {
    // Implementation for non-authenticated users
}
}
```

Open the app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file and modify the register() method as follows:

```
use App\Services\AuthService;
use App\Services\AuthenticatedAuthService;
use App\Services\NonAuthenticatedAuthService;

public function register()
{
$this->app->bind(AuthService::class, function ($app) {
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return new AuthenticatedAuthService();
    } else {
        return new NonAuthenticatedAuthService();
    }
});
}
```

In this code, we're using Laravel's service container to bind the AuthService interface to the appropriate implementation based on the user's authentication status.

Usage in Controllers or Services:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Services\AuthService;
class SomeController extends Controller
{
protected $authService;

public function __construct(AuthService $authService)
{
    $this->authService = $authService;
}

public function someMethod()
{
    $this->authService->authenticate();
    // Other code for the method
}
}
```

In this example, we're injecting the AuthService into the controller's constructor and then using it within the someMethod() to call the appropriate implementation based on the user's authentication status.

Make sure to adjust the namespaces and file locations according to your Laravel project's structure.

By following these steps, you can dynamically switch between different implementations of the AuthService based on whether the user is authenticated or not throughout your Laravel application.

Comment: This will not work, the problem is that auth()->check() returns false in ServiceProvider. And as matter of fact, if you try to use it in 'register' method of the ServciceProvider it will not even return false, it will generate an error

Comment: Actually sorry, your answer is correct. It works when I inject the service to Controller. I was actually doing this, the same way. But the problem of why it was not working for me, was that I was dumping the `auth()->check()` in the service provider, in which case the the auth havent happened yet. When I inject into controlloer, then the `bind` closure seems to only be invoked after everything is set up and then it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: A reminder that [ChatGPT is not allowed on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: Several of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469738/python-pywinauto-how-to-control-custom-gui-gui-made-by-c-or-c-want-control/76469744#76469744